# Change selector/box color and styling

Tags: jquery, selectable

Working on image crop using Selectable. 
How do I change standard selector (dotted box which draws when selecting) color and other styles?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the UI Selectable library, therefor you will need to modify the `.ui-selectable-helper` CSS class.

It's current definition can be seen at https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css